# How to free a returned malloced string?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have the following two functions. Function `get_string_data(line)` mallocs a string and returns it. Later I use it like this:

```
char *get_string_data(char *) {
    char *sec_tok, *result;
    Split *split;
    split = split_string(line, ' ');

    sec_tok = split -> tail;

    if (starts_with_char(sec_tok, '\"') && ends_with_char(sec_tok, '\"')) {
        result = (char *) malloc(strlen(sec_tok) + 1);
        strcpy(result, sec_tok);
        free(split);
        result++;
        *(result + (strlen(result) - 1)) = '\0';
        return result;
    }
    free(split);
    return NULL;
}

void handle_string_instr(char *line) {
    char* data = get_string_data(line);

    ...a few lines later, after I used the data...

    free(data);
    ... end of the world happens here...
}
```

Now on attempt to free the string everything crashes *(Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.)*. Why does this happen, and what is the correct way to free the memory?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the `char*` being returned from `get_string_data` is being allocated with `malloc`? I would expect this type of behavior if you freed say a stack based array

Comment: Is data being used by something else at some point?

Comment: @JaredPar if it was stack based, wouldn't it be out of scope once get_string_data() returns? And therefore undefined?

Comment: Added the first function code

Comment: @ScottyBauer indeed. It would possibly explain the behavior that the OP was describing.

Comment: @JaredPar Gotcha. Yevgeniy Are you modifying the data pointer at all with ++ or += etc?

Comment: Yup, I understood my mistake already. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the problem code

```
result = (char *) malloc(strlen(sec_tok) + 1);
...
result++;
...
return result;
```

At this point the `get_string_data` method is no longer returning a pointer to the memory that was allocated.  It is instead returning a pointer into the memory that was allocated.  You can only pass pointers to memory that was allocated to `free`.  In this case you don't and this is why it is crashing

Also a simpler way of null terminating the string would be the following

```
size_t length = strlen(sec_tok);
result = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
...
result[length] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

`free(line)` get_string_data possibly moves the pointer to some location in "line" which is not the correct pointer to return to free().